# Django/Python requirements.txt get always recent package

Tags: python, django

When I create my requirements.txt I always want it to get the most recent package, without me having to know  a version number, how can I do this?

For example I want this to get the latest version of Django:

**requirements.txt**

> Django>=
>
> South==0.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't specify a version number

```
Django
South==0.7.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a bit of a bad idea. The idea of having a requirements.txt is that you can perfectly replicate what you have on the machine you develop on, i.e exactly the environment it works on.

You can do what you want by just not specifying a version number in requirements.txt, but you are better off manually upgrading each module/package and confirming it works before using it in production.